# Sinch Get receiving call in background

Tags: ios, push-notification, sinch, callkit

When the app is in background/not in memory, and it receives a new call, the method **didReceiveIncomingCall**, is not executed until I open the app, so for instance if I decline the call in the **Callkit Screen**, I don't have the reference for the **ISINCALL** so I can't Hangout the call.

Is there any other way to get the **ISINCALL** call reference?

**EDIT:**

I have been searching and found this info on Sinch Docs:

**client:willReceiveIncomingCall:**

> Tells the delegate that an incoming call will be received. This is
>   specially useful for reporting the incoming call to CallKit when the
>   app is in background.

This is exactly what I need, but I think the xamarin sinch binding doesn't have this method?

Any solution ?

Comment: the binding is done by a third party so you probably have to bind it your self or ask the creator of that xamarin plugin

Comment: @cjensen yes, already working on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that might me interested I made a nuget package with the latest Sinch iOS VOICE SDK W/ VIDEO, that fix this issue.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/JoaoPalma.Sinch.iOS